# "Пилёный" или "пиленный"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "горбыль сухой пилёный" или "горбыль сухой пиленный"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: горбыль сухой **пилёный**.

**ПИЛЁНЫЙ,**  Приготовленный посредством пиления, распиленный на части. П-ые дрова. П-ое дерево. Запах пилёных досок.

Это **прилагательное,** образованное от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида: пилить - пилёный.

Сравнить: пиленные пилой брёвна,  **причастие** при наличии зависимого слова, две буквы НН.

Пример: В XVIII-XIX вв. для облицовки использовали **пилёный шпон** толщиной 1. 5… [Татьяна Матвеева. Реставрация столярно-мебельных изделий (1988)]