# Не*пилёный: слитно/раздельно

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Имеем прилагательное ***пилёный***.

> ПИЛЁНЫЙ, *прил*. Приготовленный посредством пиления, распиленный на
>   части. *Пилёные дрова. Пилёное дерево...*

Часто встречаются рекламные объявления: ***"Дрова/горбыль пилёные(-й), не_пилёные(-й)".***
Везде и повсюду пишут эту несчастную НЕ отдельно, но почему? Какие здесь есть основания для раздельного написания? Неужели это отрицание?

Или вот есть предложение: ***"Сейчас непилёные дрова стоят столько-то..."***
Здесь уж явно раздельно не напишешь, так? Но вездесущее раздельное написание сводит с ума... И, как назло, ни в одном имеющемся под рукой словаре именно этого примера нет.

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430424/Пилёный-или-пиленный

Comment: Удвоенная Н меня не интересует. Вопрос в написании с НЕ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, *непиленый* можно заменить на *цельный*, поэтому пишется слитно.

> За забором, устроенным из двух длинных **непиленых** дерев, слегка приподнятых одно над другим и привязанных к воткнутым в землю шестам, толкаются между толстыми подсолнушниками маленькие деревенские девчонки и мальчонки. [Г. И. Успенский. В деревне (Летние сцены) (1865)]

Answer (score 2):

**Из каталога дров:**

Горбыль БЕРЕЗОВЫЙ непиленый. КАМАЗ 10 кубов
Уложенный плотно пачками размером от 4 до 6 метров. Объём не менее 10 куб.

http://drova74.blizko.ru/tovary